# ASP.NET Core MVC Windows Event Logging not changing Event ID

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, event-log, ilogger

I am attempting to change the Event ID of an event in the windows application log.

In `Program.cs` > `CreateHostBuilder`, I have this:

```
    .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
    {
        logging.ClearProviders();
        logging.AddDebug().AddEventLog();
    })
```

And when attempting to log an event from a controller, I run this:

```
_logger.LogError(4472, "Event");
```

Where `_logger` is of type `ILogger` and is created via dependancy injection

This outputs to the windows event log, however the Event ID is 1000, not 4472 (or any other integer I have tried) and the second line of the event message is `EventId:4472`

Additionally, and potentially linked both `_logger.LogTrace(...)` and `_logger.LogInformation(...)` do not output anything. Despite an entry in `appsettings.json` of:

```
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Trace"
    }
  },
```

Removing the call to `ClearAllProviders()` makes the events appear in the console, this logs the Trace and Information also, though there is no id to check if that part is working.

Answer (score 0):

I see this is an older post but maybe this will help someone coming across it.
What I did was pass EventLogSettings with a Source Name into the AddEventLog method.

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var eventLogSettings = new EventLogSettings { SourceName = "EnterNameForSourceHere" };
builder.Logging.AddEventLog(eventLogSettings);
```

*Note that you have to make sure that the Source you decided on exists in the registry (i.e. Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services\EventLog\Application\EnterNameForSourceHere)*

You could also just use the name of your project as the Source (with more concise syntax):

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
builder.Logging.AddEventLog(s => { s.SourceName = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetName().Name; });
```